# Javascript muting/unmuting music via document.cookie

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to make a mute/unmute button on every click, but whenever I mute/unmute, it does mute but it never unmutes the music cause I think the cookie is not changing to 0 and I don't know what is the problem. Here's my source

```html
<script>
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
</script>
<center><ul class="navbar">
 <li class="navbar"><a href="#" onclick="homeHome()" >Home</a></li>
 <li class="navbar"><a href="/forum/index.php" onclick="homeForum()">Forum</a></li>
 <li class="navbar"><span style="cursor:pointer"><a onclick="getStatusOnBlog()">Blog</a></span></li>
 <li class="navbar"><a href="#claninfo" onclick="scrollToClanInfo()">Clan Information</a></li>
 <li class="navbar" id="colorofmute"><a href="#music" onclick="muted()">Music</a></li>
</ul></center>
<script>
function muted() {
 var mutemusic = getCookie("setMusic");
 console.log(mutemusic);
 if (mutemusic = "0") {
  x.pause();
  document.cookie = "setMusic=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";
  document.cookie = "setMusic=1; expires=Friday, Dec 9999 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
  checkIfMuted();
 } else {
  x.play();
  document.cookie = "setMusic=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";
  document.cookie = "setMusic=0; expires=Friday, Dec 9999 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
  checkIfMuted();
 };
}

function checkIfMuted() {
 var mutemusic = getCookie("setMusic");
 if (mutemusic == "1") {
  x.pause();
  document.getElementById("colorofmute").style.background = "red";
 };
 if (mutemusic == "0") {
  x.play();
  backgroundAudio('0.4');
  document.getElementById("colorofmute").style.background = "white";
 };
};
checkIfMuted();
</script>
```

You can check in https://ready4war.net/index.php and click on "Music" and tell me what is the problem, but whenever I switch stuff around, it unmutes, but it stays unmuted until I switch stuff around.

Comment: Why, specifically, are you using cookies for a mute/unmute feature. And, more in general, why are you using cookies, rather than `localStorage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the asssignment operator inside a condition (3rd line in `muted()`). Common mistake. I eliminated some semicolons. Hope it helps.

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function muted() {
    var mutemusic = getCookie("setMusic");
    console.log(mutemusic);
    if (mutemusic == "0") {
        x.pause();
        document.cookie = "setMusic=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";
        document.cookie = "setMusic=1; expires=Friday, Dec 9999 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        checkIfMuted();
    } else {
        x.play();
        document.cookie = "setMusic=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/";
        document.cookie = "setMusic=0; expires=Friday, Dec 9999 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        checkIfMuted();
    }
}

function checkIfMuted() {
    var mutemusic = getCookie("setMusic");
    if (mutemusic == "1") {
        x.pause();
        document.getElementById("colorofmute").style.background = "red";
    }

    if (mutemusic == "0") {
        x.play();
        backgroundAudio('0.4');
        document.getElementById("colorofmute").style.background = "white";
    }

}

checkIfMuted();
```